# $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x(1+a\cos x)-b\sin x}{x^3}=1$, how to find the constants $a,b$?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

I need help with this question urgently. I used L’Hospital's rule to get the second equation $$\frac{(1+a \cos x - a \sin x - b \cos x)}{3 x^2} = 1.$$

I am stuck after this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use Taylor series, the numerator is$$x(1+a-ax^2/2)-b(x-x^3/6)+o(x^3)=(1+a-b)x+(b-3a)x^3/6+o(x^3).$$Solving $1+a-b=0,\,b-3a=6$ gives $a=-\frac52,\,b=-\frac32$.

Comment: I am confused about this working

Comment: @user754578 Thanks for accepting my answer, but if you're still confused about anything, let me know what needs a further explanation.

Comment: How do you use the Taylor series to determine the answer?

Comment: @user754578 By writing $\cos x=1-\frac12x^2+o(x^3),\,\sin x=x-\frac16x^3+o(x^3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Apply L'Hopital's rule again:

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x(1+a\cos x)-b\sin x}{x^3}&\overset{LHR}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+(a-b)\cos x-ax\sin x}{3x^2}\\&\overset{LHR}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(b-2a)\sin x-ax\cos x}{6x}
\end{align*}$$

and recall that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$.

Comment: Is it possible to apply it again as the numerator does not show that it is 0.

Comment: And from (b-2a)sinx/6x how to factories (b-2a) from sinx? Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, doing so gives $$(\text{limit})\overset{LHR}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(b-3a)\cos x+ax\sin x}6=\frac{b-3a}6=1$$But my point was that this is unnecessary, and the limit can be evaluated as-is, since$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(b-2a)\sin x}{6x}=\frac{b-2a}6\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=\frac{b-2a}6$$while $\frac{ax\cos x}{6x}\overset{x\to0}\to\frac a6$, giving the same result.

Comment: Ok thank you so much. I gotten the answer!